# Non-Circular JSON returning circular JSON error

Tags: node.js, json, express

I am sending a GET request to a route and it is supposed to respond with JSON, but it returns with `Converting circular structure to JSON` error. I have tried projecting the fields that I wanted, but that didn't prevent this error. None of the objects I'm returning return themselves. And when I return the value of one of the objects, it returns fine.

This is the code for the route:

```
router.get('/', auth.required, (req, res, next) => {
  const email = jwt.verify(req.cookies.dbmtg_jwt, 'secret', function (err, decoded) {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    return decoded.email
  })
  const user = User.findOne({'email': email}, function (err, user) {
    if (err) {
      throw err
    }
    console.log(user)
  }).select({'_id': 0, 'hash': 0, 'salt': 0, '__v': 0})
  return res.json(user)
})
```

The `user` JSON I'm trying to return is not circular. It is `{ email: 'myemail@gmail.com', cardCollection: [], decks: [] }`. Even if I'm not projecting the fields I want for the JSON response (see below), I still get that error.

```
{ _id: 5c905ca89b61bb3f6f556d06,
  email: 'myemail@gmail.com',
  cardCollection: [],
  decks: [],
  salt: 'a3ff9ec1a7f76a018a7608c98f0be53e',
  hash: '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',
  __v: 0 }
```

Comment: Give `res.status(200).send(user)` a try

Comment: @mralanlee I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `const user` is not holding the actual user that's returned from the database
- Instead of returning `user` from the call to `User.find()`, try using the `user` that's returned in the **callback** `function(err, user) {}`

---

```
User.findOne({'email': email}, function (err, user) {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  } else {
    // return the JSON here
    return res.json(user);
  }
}).select({'_id': 0, 'hash': 0, 'salt': 0, '__v': 0});
```